# Python: How To create new data-frame with 2 data-frames that datas from one of those two have to be replaced by other's column name

Tags: python, dataframe, quantitative-finance

All I want to do is to create a stocks' decile frame by industry factor model.

So far, I've made a decile frame based on industry's factor named as zongmok

[image: zongmok]

And a frame called inds that shows information about which industry does stock belong to.

[image: inds]

The problem is that how to create a new data frame to show each stock's decile based on industry factor at every index time. (The new data frame is called df, and I've tried to use squared for loop, But It was too slow to complete the whole task.)

[image: df]

Here's the code I've tried:

```py
for i in notebook.tqdm(range(len(df))):
    for j in notebook.tqdm(range(len(df.columns))):
        try:
            df[df.columns[j]].loc[df.index[i]] = zongmok[inds.loc[df.index][inds == zongmok.columns[j]].dropna(axis=1)[inds[inds == zongmok.columns[j]].dropna(axis=1).columns[j]].loc[df.index[i]]].loc[df.index[i]]
        except Exception:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Can you show us your tried code, output, and the expected output? We're expecting to put aome efforts in your post so we can be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you.

Expected output looks like the image3 (df) I uploaded. (columns = stock codes, values = each tics' industry factor decile)

zongmok shows the whole industries' decile

Comment: ave you tried to use `merge()` instead of all that loop ?

Comment: lemme give you an example

Comment: Sorry for bothering you Dr. Xavier. Can you please check the following images https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP9Yg.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANHgv.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/0olNt.png ? I think function merge() can not solve this issue as all i wanted is just to subdivide industries’ data to indivisual stocks’ data

Answer (score 0):

By using `merge()` it will be easier for you to `join` two dataframe together without all of these iterations;

Example:

I've dataframe called `prod_df` and I want to merge it with another dataframe called `market_df`. This's how it goes:

**Dataframe of `prod_df`**:

[image]

**Dataframe of `market_df`**:

[image]

**Code Syntax for merging them using `Inner Join`:

```
# Lets join the two dataframe depending on `prod_df
second_merge_df = pd.merge(prod_df, market_df, how='inner', on='Prod_id')
second_merge_df.sort_values(by='Prod_id', ascending=True)
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]